# How to find which process is responsibile for a RAM burst?

Tags: vps, memory

my VPS just ran out of RAM and I was forced to reboot it since I wasn't even able to ssh in.

My question is where should I look at (logs, etc) to find out which process was responsibile for the RAM burst?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you see something in `/var/log/messages` (or some other file in `/var/log` - look around)  you blew your chance: By rebooting you destroyed any state information your system had, and now you need to wait for the problem to happen again.

If you suspect a RAM leak I suggest monitoring your RAM/Swap usage and noting any processes that appear to be growing over time.

Answer (score 1):

When you can login, type `top` and press <kbd>M</kbd> (you can also do it with `atop, htop`, ...)

If you want to check the size (in kiloBytes) instead of percentage:

```
# ps -eo rss,pid,user,cmd --sort -rss | head
```

Comment: Good procedure, but he needs the problem to happen again first.
Might be beneficial to leave a terminal open running `top` so when the system blows up again that screen can be consulted.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a metric collection system like Munin or Cacti for historical graphing of your services.

Comment: +1 for general sanity: properly configured monitoring & alerting will also warn you *before* the problem becomes so serious that you can't log in (say 80% of swap in use, or 80% of RAM if you have no swap)